# json decode not fetching url

Tags: json, curl

```
   if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
     {
     $f_name = $_FILES["filetoupload"]["name"];
     $f_tmp = $_FILES["filetoupload"]["tmp_name"];
     $store = "uploads/".$f_name;
     if(move_uploaded_file($f_tmp,$store))
      {
          echo "file uploaded successfully";``
           echo"<br>";
      }
      $f_open = fopen($store,"r");
      $line = fgets($f_open);
     $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";
     $furl ="$url"."$line";
     echo "$furl";
         $ch = curl_init();
         $fp = fopen("example4.txt","w");
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $furl);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '10.10.80.11:3128');
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

         curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch);
         fclose($fp);
```

json decod couldn't fetch the text file

```
         $jsondata = file_get_contents('example4.txt',true);
         $data=json_decode($jsondata,true); 
         echo "$data";
       (line 50)  $address=$data->results[0]->address_components; 
         echo "$address";
```

}
    here json decode seems not working as it is not taking the arrays
       and also not the url isn't passsing through curl.and errorr is Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpprog\upload_file_add.php on line 50... any help would be
          appreciate

Comment: So what are the contents of the file `example4.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the contents of `example4.txt` are a valid JSON result returned from the Google API: your data is mostly arrays instead of objects so you'll need to access it as follows:

```
$address=$data['results'][0]['address_components'];
print_r($address);
$long_name=$address[0]['long_name'];
echo $long_name;
```

Comment: thanx a lot!  but sir Hans Z. actually JSON result is not returning by the curl in the example4.txt.. how do I have solve this problem